# is there a reliable way to find the path of a physical SD card

Tags: android, filesystems, storage

I know that this topic is actively discussed, but I couldn't find a proper answer. I'm creating a simple file explorer as a part of my app and currently I'm completely confused by the android file system.

First question: I'm testing on LG Nexus 5 which does not have a physical SD of course. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns **/storage/emulated/0** and I'm able to list all of my dirs and files using this path. But now the magic begins:

Using the shell I could find 2 dirs (*/emulated/legacy* and *sdcard0*) with the same content (same result as when using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`). But there is no *../emulated/0*  path which is given by the above method o.0  What the hell is this?

[image]

[image]

Second question: as far as I could understand, the only way of finding a **physical SD card** is finding the list of paths used by different manufacturers and checking if any of them exists. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Right, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the path to the top of the "primary" shared storage on the device, which many devices choose to emulate on top of internal storage.

Starting in KitKat you have access to "secondary" shared storage devices through `Context.getExternalFilesDirs()` and `Context.getExternalCacheDirs()`.  There are also backwards-compatible versions of these APIs in the support-v4 package.

Note that there are currently no APIs for determining the top-level path of secondary storage devices.  If absolutely needed, you can derive them by shaving parent directories off one at a time until `Environment.getStorageState()` returns `MEDIA_UNKNOWN`.

Beyond these public APIs, any additional details you uncover by exploring procfs, etc are implementation details that may change in future Android releases.  For example, the duplicated mount points are present due to how shared storage separation works on multi-user devices, using Linux mount namespaces.  More technical details here:

http://source.android.com/devices/tech/storage/index.html#multi-user-external-storage